# MySQL Truncates 0 in VARCHAR field

Tags: mysql

I have a `VARCHAR` field in a MySQL table like so -

```
CREATE TABLE desc(
    `pk` varchar(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    ...
);
```

The value in pk field is of the type - (xx0000001, xx0000002, ...). But when I insert these into my table the values in `pk` field get truncated to (xx1, xx2, ...).

How to prevent this?

**UPDATE:** Adding the `INSERT`statement

```
INSERT INTO desc (pk) VALUES ("xx0000001");
```

Comment: What does your insert statement look like?

Comment: thought you would ask this :) updated the Q.

Comment: Checked your queries against MySQL 5.1.38, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the viewer you are using to LOOK at the values is displaying the info incorrectly because it is trying to interpret that string as a number, or that mysql may be interpreting your numbers as hexadecimal or something strange.

What happens if you do

```
INSERT INTO desc (pk) VALUES ("xx0000099");
```

Does it come back as xx99? or some other value?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referencing different tables in your two statements, text and desc?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly somewhere along your program logic the value is interpreted as a hexadecimal or octal number?